# Error trying to access a struct type using a pointer to a vector of structs

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, dereference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct a_struct { int an_int; };

int main () 
{
    vector <vector <a_struct> > the_vec;
    vector <a_struct> * p_vs;
    p_vs = & the_vec[0];
    *(p_vs)[0].an_int=0;   //error: 'class __gnu_debug_def::vector<a_struct,
                           //std::allocator<a_struct> >' has no member named 'an_int'
}
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting the above compile error.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `*(p_vs)[0]` has type `vector<a_struct>`.

Comment: @Ray That shouldn't be the case. How does that follow from the code?

Comment: I gave an answer below.  It is because of precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `[]` and `.` have higher precedence than `*`.

Your last line

```
*(p_vs)[0].an_int=0;
```

when fully parenthesized, is

```
*((p_vs[0]).an_int)=0;
```

Since `p_vs` was declared as

```
vector <a_struct> * p_vs;
```

it is as if `p_vs` is an array of `vector <a_struct>` elements, so `p_vs[0]` is a `vector<a_struct>`.

And `vector<a_struct>` objects indeed do not have a member `an_int`.

Add some parens and you will get what you want.

Comment: Ok, I see. The `*` goes inside the parens. Thanks.